# Include CSS file in JS

Tags: javascript, variable, snippets, global-variables, js

I have a problem with url in js file
First, in Snippets i have code

In that init.js i have that

```
(function($) {

skel.init({
    reset: 'full',
    breakpoints: {
        global:     { range: '*', href: '{stylesheet=global_embeds/style}', containers: 1400, grid: { gutters: 50 } },
        wide:       { range: '-1680', href: '{stylesheet=global_embeds/style-wide}', containers: 1200, grid: { gutters: 40 } },
        normal:     { range: '-1280', href: '{stylesheet=global_embeds/style-normal}', containers: 960, grid: { gutters: 30 }, viewport: { scalable: false } },
        narrow:     { range: '-980', href: '{stylesheet=global_embeds/style-narrow}', containers: '95%', grid: { gutters: 20 } },
        narrower:   { range: '-840', href: '{stylesheet=global_embeds/style-narrower}', grid: { collapse: 1 } },
        mobile:     { range: '-736', href: '{stylesheet=global_embeds/style-mobile}', containers: '90%', grid: { gutters: 15 } },
        mobilep:    { range: '-480', href: '{stylesheet=global_embeds/style-mobilep}', grid: { collapse: 2 }, containers: '100%' }
    },
```

In template group global_embeds i have all this files

BUT link {stylesheet=global_embeds/style-mobile} doesn't work on js file

What to do? Who know? =(

Comment: what do you mean by 'doesn't work on js file'? Is not link to this file? You have link but you can't open it? What do you see in this file? All other links is fine(for example global_embeds/style-mobilep)? Did you try to rename this template?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the [stylesheet tag](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/stylesheet.html#stylesheet-global-variable) needs quotation marks.

```
{stylesheet="global_embeds/style"}
```

If you link to the JS file using [`path` variable](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/path.html), all the templates variables on the linked file will be parsed.

```
{path="global_embeds/init.js"}
```

But I really don't think it's good for performance. It's much better to use static links for the JS and CSS.